# Calling setRowHeight on JTable immediately resets int method argument

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am having trouble understanding why this might be happening.  I have been searching online for a similar problem but couldn't find one.

```
for ( int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++ ) {
        int rowHeight = this.getRowHeight();
        for ( int col = 0; col < this.getColumnCount(); col++ ) {
           Component pRenderer = getCellRenderer( row, col );
        // Assume this is a dimension of 120x120
        Dimension pRendererSize = pRenderer.getPreferredSize();
           if ( pRendererSize.height  > rowHeight )
            rowHeight = pRendererSize.height;
        }
     this.setRowHeight( row, rowHeight );
}
```

The default height for a row in my JTable is 16 pixels.  If I make the call:

```
//This returns 16 initially
this.getRowHeight();
```

I am stepping through the code in my debugger.  At the line setRowHeight the argument rowHeight is 120 thus I am setting the rowHeight of my row to 120 pixels.  I did not overload this method at all, this is the JTable implementation of setRowHeight.

What happens next is truly frightening.  After stepping over this method, not only does this.getRowHeight() still return 16 pixels, the value of rowHeight immediately changes to 16 pixels.

Of course the table renders incorrectly too.  This seems to defy sense that my int value type argument would change by passing it to a method.  This should not change the rowHeight variable at all.  Do you think my debugger is running on old code, is broken or could this be the end of times?

Comment: Post your SSCCE (http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: A little more information, I tried doing this very simply from the Display window while still inside this method in the debugger and this behavior didn't occur, however the row height on my table is still 16 pixels.

Comment: I don't see a problem with you code, it looks very similiar to mine. Maybe you have two instance of JTable (one in memory and one added to the frame) and you are updating the row height of the one in memory which won't affect the one in the frame). Without a SSCCE we can't only guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code I use to set row heights:

```
private void updateRowHeights()
{
    try
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++)
        {
            int rowHeight = table.getRowHeight();

            for (int column = 0; column < table.getColumnCount(); column++)
            {
                Component comp = table.prepareRenderer(table.getCellRenderer(row, column), row, column);
                rowHeight = Math.max(rowHeight, comp.getPreferredSize().height);
            }

            table.setRowHeight(row, rowHeight);
        }
    }
    catch(ClassCastException e) {}
}
```

[UIManager Defaults](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) uses this code. Click on "by Value Type" and then select "Icon" to see it working.

Comment: (OT: You used to help me out with Swing issues on the old Java forum before Oracle ruined it. :) It's nice to see you again) I copy and pasted this code except I removed the line fetching the Component and just passed the literal 120 into Math.max.  This STILL exhibits that same problem.

Comment: UPDATE: Strange, when I call setRowHeight outside of the loop it works fine and doesn't change the rowHeight variable @_@!

Comment: Where do you call `updateRowHeights()`? When I call it in my renderer, it seems to re-render, causing a `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: You call it after you load the data into your TableModel. You can download the code so see exactly what I do.